Forcing PowerBi to sum a column in the totals instead of applying the measure on the total row
I have this formula which works well in a row, however in the totals I don't want it to apply the measure again. Instead I need it to just add the entire column.
Code :
Absolute gap = 
VAR CurrentWeek = MAX('Revenue'[TY Week])
VAR LYHeld = CALCULATE(
SUM('Revenue'[Sales(LY)]),
FILTER('Revenue', 'Revenue'[TY Week] = CurrentWeek)
)
VAR CurrentHeld = CALCULATE(
SUM('Revenue'[Revenue(TY)]),
FILTER('Revenue', 'Revenue'[TY Week] = CurrentWeek)
)
VAR vs_BUDGET = DIVIDE(CurrentHeld, SUM('Target'[Target]))
VAR Gradient =
IF(
    MAX('Date'[Date]) < DATE(2024, 12, 11),
    1,
    DIVIDE(LYHeld, SUM('Overall Sales'[LY]))
)
VAR GAP = (NPRHELD_BUDGET - (Gradient)) * [Target]
RETURN
GAP

I was thinking of doing a calculated column. However there are 3 tables with 1- many relationship causing duplicated values

Which dimensions (columns) are using in your table/matrix? Need to know to help provide a solution using SUMX.

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output
